# full text search doesn't find anything

Tags: sql, full-text-search, phpmyadmin, myisam

**EDIT****

ok so i found the problam, it was that the min word length for the search was 4, i changed it to 3 but now it only finds the row 1 data and not row 2 data aswell...

**-----original question:----**

I have a MyISAM table on my phpmyadmin like this:

```
table name: `users`
coulmn name: `name`
row 1 data: 'dan'
row 2 data: 'dan252'
```

(it's just the important part of it)

now the name is fulltext index field, im using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST('dan')
```

but phpmyadmin returns:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )
```

why it's not finding anything?

****EDIT****

ok so i found the problam, it was that the min word length for the search was 4, i changed it to 3 but now it only finds the row 1 data and not row 2 data aswell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MATCH` only works on columns with `FULLTEXT` indicing.  And `FULLTEXT` indicing only works on MyISAM tables.

Secondly, 'dan' is probably [too short](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) to use on a `MATCH`.

Thirdly, if your search term matches more than 50% of your rows, the term is considered too common and the search fails.

Have a read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('dan');

I guess you are using apostrophes for tablename and in MATCH. This is wrong. Try it and let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to return all with 'dan' in them
You could try the LIKE command.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%dan%'
```

That will return 'dan' and 'dan252' and (if he was in the table) '123dan456'.

You could also try

```
SELECT * FROM users Match(name) AGAINST('+dan*')
```

That should return the same thing and is probably more efficient.
If you are only trying to use 'dan' then use as @Kirishna says.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('dan')
```

Comment: i want to use fulltext not LIKE, the first one returns a syntax error and secound one returns an empty result

Comment: You could try `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONTAINS(name,"dan")` I took that from [Microsoft SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) so it may not work.